# Anuglar Jasmine: Unit test for conditonal statement

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

getClass is simple function that return class name. Can anyone please tell me if I missed anything in test case?

app.ts

```
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() className: string;

  getClass() {
    if (this.className === 'row') {
      this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    }
    return this.className;
  }
```

app.spec.ts

```
  it('should call getClass function and return class name', () => {
    component.className = 'row';
    const value = (component.value = 'Customer Name');
    value.toLocaleLowerCase();

    var result = component.getClass();
    // Assert
    expect(result).toBe('row');
  });
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: @slideshowp2, No error. Im new to writing test case. Just want to make sure implementation is correct